# Can a WCF NetTcpBinding duplex channel endpoint be on port 80?

Tags: .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

In several forum threads I have encountered people say, that

> netTCP cannot use port 80, so there will be firewall issue If I use
>   it for web.

If I have a Windows 2008 Server, with an IP "dedicated" to my WCF service, and will bind NetTcpBinding endpoint to port 80, will my client applications be able to access it from networks, where only access to port 80 of the external server is allowed to? Is the 80/tcp limitation purely "port-allocation"-related, or is there more to it?

Comment: I wanted to ask this question myself and would be interested to see an authoratitive answer - I think it odd it hasnt seen more input.  Anyone out there with something to add?

Answer (score 1):

My (fairly uneducated) guess is that it depends on the firewall thats managing the port.  If its a garden all adsl router with built in firewall/NAT then there is a good chance that when you say forward port 80 that is does that without checking packet content.
On the other hand in a corporate enviroment with something like a Pix firewall if you tell it forward http on port 80 its only going to do that for http packets (because its actually checking packet content) and your nettcp will get blocked.